# R: Scraping Data From a Population Pyramid

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I am working with the R programming language.

I found this link which has historical population pyramids for Canada: https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2021/dp-pd/dv-vd/pyramid/index-en.htm

[image]

**My Question:** For every year in the drop down scroll menu (i.e. 1851 - 2043), I want to get the age-gender breakdowns. This would look something like this:

```
   year gender  age percent_of_population
1  1975   Male   25                    3%
2  1975 Female   25                    2%
3  1975   Male   26                    1%
4  1975 Female   26                    2%
5  ....   ....  ...                   ...
6  1976   Male   25                    4%
7  1976 Female   25                    3%
8  1976   Male   26                    2%
9  1976 Female   26                    1%
10  ...    ... ....                   ,,,
```

So far, I am trying to look if the website itself has some button which will allow you to directly download the age-gender breakdowns for all years... but it seems I can only look at very limited information from each year.

Apart from that, I have started to "inspect" the source code of the website - but I see no "tags" that I might be able to use to understand the structure of this website.

Can someone please show me how I can solve this problem? Maybe Selenium can be useful for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript that renders charts and tables fetches data from API endpoints, the one with age-gender breakdowns is `rest/dataviz/HistoricPyramid.json`:

```r
library(dplyr)

jsonlite::fromJSON("https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/rest/dataviz/HistoricPyramid.json?dguid=2021A000011124&minYr=1975&maxYr=2043") %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  arrange(YR, AGE)
#> # A tibble: 6,969 × 7
#>    DGUID            AGE   MALE FEMALE MALEPERCENT FEMALEPERCENT    YR
#>    <chr>          <int>  <int>  <int>       <dbl>         <dbl> <int>
#>  1 2021A000011124     0 178580 169805       0.787         0.748  1975
#>  2 2021A000011124     1 175990 167720       0.775         0.739  1975
#>  3 2021A000011124     2 178500 169185       0.786         0.745  1975
#>  4 2021A000011124     3 182120 172565       0.802         0.760  1975
#>  5 2021A000011124     4 190550 181525       0.840         0.800  1975
#>  6 2021A000011124     5 191365 182020       0.843         0.802  1975
#>  7 2021A000011124     6 186855 177610       0.823         0.783  1975
#>  8 2021A000011124     7 188990 180695       0.833         0.796  1975
#>  9 2021A000011124     8 201415 192215       0.887         0.847  1975
#> 10 2021A000011124     9 212545 203455       0.936         0.896  1975
#> # ℹ 6,959 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! can you please explain how you got this "magic" to work? What exactly is "rest"? thank you!

Comment: I've attempted to to explain some scarping strategies in couple of previous posts - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A646761+search+chrome . Here I just searched for "1851" to find relevant requests. "rest" is just part of the URL, it might as well be "HereBeDragonsDoNotEnter"; though it does stand for REpresentational State Transfer and if that pops up in made requests, there's a good chance it points to some API service.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the data [here](https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/rest/dataviz/HistoricPyramid.json?dguid=2021A000011124&minYr=1851&maxYr=2050).

To reproduce the thing you want *exactly*, here is what you can do:

```r
library(dplyr)

jsonlite::fromJSON("https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/rest/dataviz/HistoricPyramid.json?dguid=2021A000011124&minYr=1851&maxYr=2050") |>
  select(year = YR, age = AGE, Male = MALEPERCENT, Female = FEMALEPERCENT) |> 
  pivot_longer(c(Male, Female), names_to = "gender", values_to = "percent_of_population") |> 
  mutate(percent_of_population = paste0(round(percent_of_population), "%")) |> 
  arrange(year, age) |>
  select(year, gender, age, percent_of_population) |>
  filter(year >= 1975, age >= 25)

# Output
# A tibble: 10,488 × 4
    year gender   age percent_of_population
   <int> <chr>  <int> <chr>                
 1  1975 Male      25 1%                   
 2  1975 Female    25 1%                   
 3  1975 Male      26 1%                   
 4  1975 Female    26 1%                   
 5  1975 Male      27 1%                   
 6  1975 Female    27 1%                   
 7  1975 Male      28 1%                   
 8  1975 Female    28 1%                   
 9  1975 Male      29 1%                   
10  1975 Female    29 1%                   
# ℹ 10,478 more rows
```

Comment: @ Mark: Thank you so much for your answer! How did you find this link? Is it accessible from the website I shared? Thank you so much!

Comment: hi @stats_noob! apologies for the hit and run answer, I had to go to work :P

Comment: my general approach with scraping-type questions is, to turn off Javascript in the browser (you can do this through uBlock Origin (if you use that adblocker) fairly easily. If the thing I'm looking for is still accessible then, then it's in the HTML, and can be scraped using rvest. If not, then I look at the Network tab of the Inspector for Firefox or Chrome, and check to see if anything interesting is downloaded when I load the page, or click on things within the element I'm interested in (e.g. does loading a new page of the search results for a shopping website download something?

Comment: in this case, the answer was yes, yes it did. It downloaded some json. If you open the page, and look at the network tab, and filter it to only json files, then you see the table data, as well as a few other things. It's quite neat!